# Slider in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, visual-studio, slider, windows-store-apps

I'm developing an music player app for windows store. But i cant handle this question.

I want to if the user holding the slider's thump, mediaElement will pause and when the user release the press, media element will play.

How can I do that?

> Note: Slider's holding event is pause the mediaelement but i cant play
>   music after holding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use ManipulationStarted and ManipulationCompleted, but first you need to set ManipulationMode="All"

```
<Slider ManipulationMode="All" ManipulationStarted="Slider_ManipulationStarted"
ManipulationCompleted="Slider_ManipulationCompleted" />
```